# How do I get a python program to do the opposite in a for loop/if statement?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

how do I get a Python for loop/if statement to do the opposite?
Namely, I would like the loop below, just adding an additional statement in the third row (between the if statement and the print statement, without changing the first, second and fourth row) to print **a, p, p, e**.

```
for i in "apple":
    if i == "l":
        # additional statement here
    print(i)
```

Can you please let me know?
Thank you very much

Comment: thank you but as mentioned in the instructions I would like to keep the first, second and fourth rows unchanged. I would like to reach the goal by adding a third row between the if and print statements

Comment: `continue` at 3rd line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for i in "apple":
    if i == "l":
        continue
    print(i)
```

What you are looking for is the `continue` statement, which exits the loop iteration and moves to the next one, in a way you can see it as the return statement for a loop.

`break` will exit the loop completely (stop iterating).

[This website explains it well](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue)